# Angular: Multiple parameters undefined when passed to express

Tags: angularjs, express

I'm trying to send multiple parameters to the backend in an `http.get` call. Issue is I don't see them in express:

Angular:

```
$http.get("/getImage/", {params: {"filename" : $scope.recipe.image.filename, "mimetype" : $scope.recipe.image.mimetype}})
.then(function(returnData){
    console.log(returnData);
})
```

Express:

```
server.get("/getImage/", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.filename);
})
```

`req.params.filename` shows up as `undefined` when logged. All help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that in express, req.params refers to path parameters, i.e. in a route like

```
app.get('/foo/:bar', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.bar);
});
```

the url has a 'bar' param because there's a parameter in the registered path called :bar. What I believe you're looking for is req.query, which turns the query parameters from the url into a json object, so if you're hitting

```
http://localhost:8080/foo?bar=baz
```

and you want to get the value of bar, you should register your route like

```
app.get('/foo', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.bar);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$http.get` in angular will produce a GET-request with the params in the url. So in Express you should be able to access them with req.query:

```
server.get("/getImage/", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.query.filename);
})
```